# HTML subsubmenu show when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a menu that has subsub items kind of like this:

```
>Menu
 >Sub-Item
  >Sub-Sub-Item
  >Sub-Sub-Item2
 >Sub-Item2
```

The issue I'm having is when I click on the Sub-Sub-Item the sub-item closes(which I don't want)

```js
function menuTrigger(e){
  if(!hasClass(e,"active")){
    e.classList.add("active");
    e.height="auto";
    var child=getNextChild(e,"UL");
    child.height=0;
    child.style.display="block";
    child.height="auto";
  }
  else{
    if(hasClass(e,"active")){
      e.classList.remove("active");
      var child=getNextChild(e,"UL");
      child.height=0;
      child.style.display="none";
      child.height="0";
    }
  }
}
function hasClass(element,selector)
{
  var className=" "+selector+" ";
  return ((" "+ element.className+ " ").replace(/[\n\t]/g," ").indexOf(className)>1)
}
function getNextChild(element,tagName){
  for(var index=0;index<element.children.length;index++)
  {
    if(element.children[index].tagName==tagName.toUpperCase())
    {
      return element.children[index];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

```css
body { background: #FFF;}
.wrap{width: 100%;max-width: 300px;margin:20px auto;}

.goo-collapsible{list-style: none;font-family: 'HelveticaNeue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px}
.goo-collapsible li.header{color: #666; padding:4px 12px;border: 1px solid #bbb;}
.goo-collapsible li { border: 1px solid #bbb;border-top:0; margin: 0;background:#F0F0F0;}
.goo-collapsible li a {  text-decoration:none; color:#666;display:block; padding:8px 12px;}
.goo-collapsible li a:hover {background: #F8F8F8; text-decoration:none;}
.goo-collapsible li ul { list-style: none; background: #d3d3d3; display: none; margin:0;padding:0;}
.goo-collapsible li ul li { margin:0; border:0; border-bottom:1px solid #bbb;}
.goo-collapsible li ul li:last-child {border-bottom:0;}
.goo-collapsible li ul li a { padding: 5px 10px; display: block; padding-left: 33px;background: #d3d3d3; }
.goo-collapsible li ul li a:hover { background: #d9d9d9; }
.goo-collapsible .dropdown > a { background: url(images/arrowdown.png) no-repeat right center; }
.goo-collapsible .dropdown > a:hover { background: #F8F8F8 url(images/arrowdown.png) no-repeat right center !important; }
.goo-collapsible li ul li ul li a{ background: #f5e6ff;}
```

```html
<div class="wrap"> 
  <ul class="goo-collapsible goo-coll-stacked">
    <li class='dropdown' onClick="menuTrigger(this);"><a class=''><span class='icon-table'></span> Formulaires</a>
      <ul>
        <li class='dropdown' onClick="menuTrigger(this);"><a>Sub-Menu</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="somesite.html" target="_blank">Sub-SubMenu1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="somesite2.html" target="_blank">Sub-SubMenu2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="blahblah.html" target="_blank">Sub-SubMenu3</a>
            </li>
            <li>    
              <a href="blahblah2.html" target="_blank">Sub-SubMenu4</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="blahblah3.html" target="_blank">Sub-SubMenu5</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li ><a href='#'>Comments</a></li>
        <li ><a href='#'>Tags</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'><span class='icon-folder-open'></span> Folder</a></li>
    <li class='dropdown' onClick="menuTrigger(this);"><a href='#'><span class='icon-user'></span> Users</a>
      <ul>
        <li ><a href='#'>Group</a></li>
        <li ><a href='#'>User</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'><span class='icon-cogs'></span> Settings</a></li>                
  </ul>    
</div>
```

Please **don't** give me an answer using JQuery or other Javascript frameworks. When I open the Menu (as it has closed when I clicked on Sub-Sub-Item) the Sub-Sub-Item is open, but I would like that when I click on Sub-Sub-Item, Sub-Item stays open as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend not inlining the event handlers in your HTML.  Instead attach event listeners via javascript.  Then once you've done that, utilize the event object that gets passed to the `menuTrigger` function to determine if the target of the event was a child menu or not.  If it is a child menu and the event is triggering for the parent, just execute a `return` at the top of the `menuTrigger` method.  Obviously the syntax used is subject to how cross browser you want to be. [`event.target` is universal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target), but [`addEventListener()` is IE 9+ only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).  Because of that limitation I've also chosen to use [`querySelectorAll()`, which is similarly IE 9+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```js
var dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.goo-collapsible .dropdown');

for(var i = 0, len = dropdowns.length; i < len; i++) {
  dropdowns[i].addEventListener('click', menuTrigger);
}

function menuTrigger(e){
  var el = this;
  if(e.target.parentNode !== el) {
    return;
  }
  if(!hasClass(el,"active")){
    el.classList.add("active");
    el.height="auto";
    var child=getNextChild(el,"UL");
    child.height=0;
    child.style.display="block";
    child.height="auto";
  }
  else{
    if(hasClass(el,"active")){
      el.classList.remove("active");
      var child=getNextChild(el,"UL");
      child.height=0;
      child.style.display="none";
      child.height="0";
    }
  }
}
function hasClass(element,selector)
{
  var className=" "+selector+" ";
  return ((" "+ element.className+ " ").replace(/[\n\t]/g," ").indexOf(className)>1)
}
function getNextChild(element,tagName){
  for(var index=0;index<element.children.length;index++)
  {
    if(element.children[index].tagName==tagName.toUpperCase())
    {
      return element.children[index];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

```css
body { background: #FFF;}
.wrap{width: 100%;max-width: 300px;margin:20px auto;}

.goo-collapsible{list-style: none;font-family: 'HelveticaNeue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px}
.goo-collapsible li.header{color: #666; padding:4px 12px;border: 1px solid #bbb;}
.goo-collapsible li { border: 1px solid #bbb;border-top:0; margin: 0;background:#F0F0F0;}
.goo-collapsible li a {  text-decoration:none; color:#666;display:block; padding:8px 12px;}
.goo-collapsible li a:hover {background: #F8F8F8; text-decoration:none;}
.goo-collapsible li ul { list-style: none; background: #d3d3d3; display: none; margin:0;padding:0;}
.goo-collapsible li ul li { margin:0; border:0; border-bottom:1px solid #bbb;}
.goo-collapsible li ul li:last-child {border-bottom:0;}
.goo-collapsible li ul li a { padding: 5px 10px; display: block; padding-left: 33px;background: #d3d3d3; }
.goo-collapsible li ul li a:hover { background: #d9d9d9; }
.goo-collapsible .dropdown > a { background: url(images/arrowdown.png) no-repeat right center; }
.goo-collapsible .dropdown > a:hover { background: #F8F8F8 url(images/arrowdown.png) no-repeat right center !important; }
.goo-collapsible li ul li ul li a{ background: #f5e6ff;}
```

```html
<div class="wrap"> 
  <ul class="goo-collapsible goo-coll-stacked">
    <li class='dropdown'><a class=''><span class='icon-table'></span> Formulaires</a>
      <ul>
        <li class='dropdown'><a>Sub-Menu</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="somesite.html" target="_blank">Sub-SubMenu1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="somesite2.html" target="_blank">Sub-SubMenu2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="blahblah.html" target="_blank">Sub-SubMenu3</a>
            </li>
            <li>    
              <a href="blahblah2.html" target="_blank">Sub-SubMenu4</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="blahblah3.html" target="_blank">Sub-SubMenu5</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li ><a href='#'>Comments</a></li>
        <li ><a href='#'>Tags</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'><span class='icon-folder-open'></span> Folder</a></li>
    <li class='dropdown'><a href='#'><span class='icon-user'></span> Users</a>
      <ul>
        <li ><a href='#'>Group</a></li>
        <li ><a href='#'>User</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'><span class='icon-cogs'></span> Settings</a></li>                
  </ul>    
</div>
```

## Edit

Or the completely obvious answer.  I can't believe I didn't see this sooner.  Just use [`event.stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

```js
var dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.goo-collapsible .dropdown');

for(var i = 0, len = dropdowns.length; i < len; i++) {
  dropdowns[i].addEventListener('click', menuTrigger);
}

function menuTrigger(e){
  var el = this;
  
  e.stopPropagation();

  if(!hasClass(el,"active")){
    el.classList.add("active");
    el.height="auto";
    var child=getNextChild(el,"UL");
    child.height=0;
    child.style.display="block";
    child.height="auto";
  }
  else{
    if(hasClass(el,"active")){
      el.classList.remove("active");
      var child=getNextChild(el,"UL");
      child.height=0;
      child.style.display="none";
      child.height="0";
    }
  }
}
function hasClass(element,selector)
{
  var className=" "+selector+" ";
  return ((" "+ element.className+ " ").replace(/[\n\t]/g," ").indexOf(className)>1)
}
function getNextChild(element,tagName){
  for(var index=0;index<element.children.length;index++)
  {
    if(element.children[index].tagName==tagName.toUpperCase())
    {
      return element.children[index];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

```css
body { background: #FFF;}
.wrap{width: 100%;max-width: 300px;margin:20px auto;}

.goo-collapsible{list-style: none;font-family: 'HelveticaNeue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px}
.goo-collapsible li.header{color: #666; padding:4px 12px;border: 1px solid #bbb;}
.goo-collapsible li { border: 1px solid #bbb;border-top:0; margin: 0;background:#F0F0F0;}
.goo-collapsible li a {  text-decoration:none; color:#666;display:block; padding:8px 12px;}
.goo-collapsible li a:hover {background: #F8F8F8; text-decoration:none;}
.goo-collapsible li ul { list-style: none; background: #d3d3d3; display: none; margin:0;padding:0;}
.goo-collapsible li ul li { margin:0; border:0; border-bottom:1px solid #bbb;}
.goo-collapsible li ul li:last-child {border-bottom:0;}
.goo-collapsible li ul li a { padding: 5px 10px; display: block; padding-left: 33px;background: #d3d3d3; }
.goo-collapsible li ul li a:hover { background: #d9d9d9; }
.goo-collapsible .dropdown > a { background: url(images/arrowdown.png) no-repeat right center; }
.goo-collapsible .dropdown > a:hover { background: #F8F8F8 url(images/arrowdown.png) no-repeat right center !important; }
.goo-collapsible li ul li ul li a{ background: #f5e6ff;}
```

```html
<div class="wrap"> 
  <ul class="goo-collapsible goo-coll-stacked">
    <li class='dropdown'><a class=''><span class='icon-table'></span> Formulaires</a>
      <ul>
        <li class='dropdown'><a>Sub-Menu</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="somesite.html" target="_blank">Sub-SubMenu1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="somesite2.html" target="_blank">Sub-SubMenu2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="blahblah.html" target="_blank">Sub-SubMenu3</a>
            </li>
            <li>    
              <a href="blahblah2.html" target="_blank">Sub-SubMenu4</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="blahblah3.html" target="_blank">Sub-SubMenu5</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li ><a href='#'>Comments</a></li>
        <li ><a href='#'>Tags</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'><span class='icon-folder-open'></span> Folder</a></li>
    <li class='dropdown'><a href='#'><span class='icon-user'></span> Users</a>
      <ul>
        <li ><a href='#'>Group</a></li>
        <li ><a href='#'>User</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'><span class='icon-cogs'></span> Settings</a></li>                
  </ul>    
</div>
```

Comment: I looked into stopping the propagation of the event and by adding

               var evt=window.event;
                if(evt.stopPropagation)
                { 
                    evt.stopPropagation();
                }
                if(evt.cancelBubble!=null)
                {
                    evt.cancelBubble=true;
                }
to the each if statement it seems to stop the propagation to the parent UL

Comment: Not kidding you, I am just editing my answer because of `stopPropagation`.  I feel stupid for not thinking of it in the first place.

Comment: @James Yeah.  That was a complete lapse of thought there.  `event.preventDefault` even has the same support of IE9+

Comment: Setting cancelBubble (even though deprecated is supported in IE6+) will cancel event on older browsers, that's why I was checking if it exists first.